# How to setup Review-aggregate with schema.org?

Tags: html, google-search, schema.org

I have a project - http://preloaders.net. I have set it up so that rating is shown in google search (the orange stars under the title, e.g. try entering preloader spinner keywords ). Everything is working fine, except for home page as I just fixed it.

I am re-coding the whole markup now to HTML5 (which I am pretty new to) and use schema.org and include all products to the whole schema, but I do not know what the substitute for Review-aggregate in schema.org is, so I am trying WebPage. Google webmaster does not show errors, but the question is: will the following code still show the stars or should I do something else?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>my title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href=""></a>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <section>
                <h1>AJAX LOADERS</h1>
                <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                    <figure>
                        <img itemprop="image" src="/preloader.gif" alt="">
                        <figcaption itemprop="description">
                            Spinning Christmas tree with balls.
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <a href="#" title="#" itemprop="url">
                        <h3 itemprop="name">3D Christmas tree </h3>
                    </a>
                    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span><span class="price" itemprop="price">2.95</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="favorite"></div>
                    <div class="add-to-cart"></div>
                    <div class="frames-amount">30 fr</div>
                    <div class="dimensions">256x256</div>
                    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                        Average Rating: <span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span>
                        Votes: <span itemprop="ratingCount">12</span>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </section>
            <aside>
                <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                    <a href="/en/free">
                        <h3 itemprop="name">Free templates</h3>
                        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                            <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span><span class="price" itemprop="price">0</span>
                        </div>
                        <div itemprop="description">
                            Spinning Christmas tree with balls.
                        </div>
                        <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                            Average Rating: <span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span>
                            Votes: <span itemprop="ratingCount">12</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </article>
            </aside>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <nav>
                <a href=""></a>
            </nav>
        </footer>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        { "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "WebPage",
          "name": "Loading GIF & APNG (AJAX loaders) generator",
          "description": "More than 800 free and premium ajax loader (loading animated GIF and APNG) spinners, bars and 3D animations generator for AJAX and JQuery",
          "aggregateRating":
            {"@type": "AggregateRating",
             "ratingValue": "4.9",
             "reviewCount": "7",
             "itemReviewed": "AJAX loaders generator"
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Sorry for noob question, just need to make sure I am in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Is there a reason why you use Microdata for the two `Product` items and JSON-LD for the `WebPage` item? 2) "AJAX loaders generator" is a single page where you can generate the images, right? And the rating is about how good this generator is?

Comment: 1) It's more convenient for me to separate products rating and page. But I can use JSON-LD too. Just don't want too many <script></script> thingies
2) Yes, it is a single page, but there are many of those. The title is just as an  example. This is an example code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is an example of what you have to do](https://whitespark.ca/blog/how-to-use-aggregate-review-schema-to-get-stars-in-the-serps/)

[And here is the official documentation](https://schema.org/AggregateRating)

What you've done is versy similar to the code from the exampple so I guess that what you've done is enough to have the stars

Comment: Thanks a lot. The thing is in the article you provided from webspark.ca - they are setting the "@type" to product, while in the page they show that they have in google they use "@type":"Service". I can't find anywhere what I should place in case I need to rate the page itself.